# Angular 5 Formdata with Ä Ö Ü as values

Tags: angular, post, utf-8, header, form-data

I want to uplade files to a server. 
So i append them into a formdata

```
  let formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('value1', 'ÖÄÜ');
  formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
```

and try to post them to the server

```
 this.http.post(`uploadURL`, formData)
        .subscribe(
        data => console.log('success'),
        error => console.log(error)
        )
```

But in the the post are these Chars displayed wrong (except the part in the textfile)

```
-----------------------------
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="value1"

ÃÃÃ
-----------------------------
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadFile"; filename="ÃÃÃ.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

ÖÄÜ
-------------------------------
```

But when I stop to append a file into the formdata the Ä Ö Ü are displayed fine.

```
-----------------------------
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="value1"

ÖÄÜ
-----------------------------
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadFile"; filename="ÖÜÄ.txt"

-------------------------------
```